# Trigger Azure VM scripts via Azure Databricks workflow

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-virtual-machine

I have some scripts in Azure Virtual Machine that can only be executed there. And I want to be able to trigger these AVM scripts by an Azure Databricks workflow. I am giving some input variables and receiving some outputs.

I followed these steps, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject , creating a AVM and a Databricks Workspace under the same VNetwork. Then, I tried unsuccessfully to connect to the AVM via ssh in a Databricks notebook.
However, I got an: *ssh: connect to host myvirtualmachine.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com port 22: Connection timed out*
But the ssh port is available:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aUkn.png)

In conclusion, I cannot connect to do that last step to trigger the script. Is that even possible? In this case, I want to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: what is the command you tried to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Interactive input is not supported in Databricks. You need to run a script that does login and executes the script. Use the script below:

```
SSH_SERVER="194.xx.xxx.16"    
SSH_PORT="22"   
SSH_USER="demo"    
SSH_PASSWORD="password"       

REMOTE_COMMAND="ls -l readme.txt"
    
sshpass -p "$SSH_PASSWORD" ssh -p $SSH_PORT  $SSH_USER@$SSH_SERVER  "$REMOTE_COMMAND"
```

Here, I have given the command as `ls`. Instead, you should provide the command to run the script with the script path, like:

```
REMOTE_COMMAND="bash /path/to/script/"
```

Output:

```
-rw------- 1 demo users 379 Sep 19 13:12 readme.txt
```

Make sure to install `sshpass`.

```bash
sudo apt install sshpass
```